# Devise edit_password_url missing /

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've write a RoR application and I use Devise for some user management.

I've already configure my application to send email for password recovery and I use the following code in my `reset_password_instruction.html.erb`:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Modify password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>
```

In my config environment files I have defined: `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'app_url.com' }`.

When the application send a recovery email, it attach an url like this:
`app_url.comuser` insted of `app_url.com/user`.

What did I miss?

From the rails console, I see the url like it is suppposed to be.

```
<p><a href=3D"http://app_url.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_=token=3D47da8a08bd3d4asdfadfasdfa3eb9422388467adccfe095f058ca2a3352b12"=>Modify password</a></p>
```